# Use isinstance with an undefined class

Tags: python, isinstance

Assume that class `MyClass` is sometimes, but not always, defined. I have a function `foo(a=None)` in which argument `a` can be `None`, a string, or an object of `MyClass`.

My question is: If `MyClass` is not defined in my Python session, how can I check the type of argument `a` in a fashion similar to `isinstance` without getting a `NameError`?

Note on duck-typing: I am deliberately limiting the function.

I'm using Python 2.6.x and Updating is not an option. A forward-compatible solution (especially for 2.7.x) is highly appreciated.

Comment: Simple, if it isn't defined, you get a `NameError`. There's no way around it

Comment: Why would your class be *defined* conditionally?!

Comment: Use `try-except`. If your class isn't defined then it's a given that no object would  be an instance of it.

Comment: `try-except` is probably the best suggestion.  You can also check that `a` is not *not* `MyClass`: `isinstance(a, (str, type(None)))`.

Comment: @deceze The function will be used in both a stand-alone interpreter and an embedded one. The class can only be defined in the embedded interpreter. In fact, valid string and `MyClass` values both `__str()__` to the same string.

Comment: Mightn't it make more sense to define the class either way, but have it behave differently in different environments? That's kind of a fundamental idea of OOP.

Comment: @deceze I wasn't clear enough. `MyClass` is a propriety class belonging to the embedded Python that I'm using.

Comment: I'd still go with *conditionally defining* the class then; i.e. if the class doesn't exist natively, define your own replacement instead. Makes all code referring to this class simpler. That of course still leaves sort of the same question…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach: polyfill the class so all code that wants to refer to it can simply do so:

```
try:
    from foo import Bar  # load the native class
except ImportError:
    class Bar:
        pass  # implement necessary parts here
```

You can put this into your own module and then `from mymodule import Bar` everywhere it's needed. That allows all your code to use `Bar` regardless of whether it's defined natively or not.

Even if redefining the class isn't your preferred way to handle this, handling the `ImportError` is still the way to handle this situation, since you will have to `import` the class either way and that's where the error will occur. Instead of defining the class, you may instead want to set a `class_exists = False` flag or something.

Comment: I've adapted your answer. If `class_exists=False`, `(class_exists and isinstance(a, MyClass) )` won't throw an error due to short-circuiting.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyClass` isn't defined then you have no way to reference its type.

Therefore you can have no way to verify that `type(a)` has the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

I workarounded the problem by **overriding a method** in `MyClass` and doing nothing in it (`pass`). After that I no longer needed to check its type.

Different workarounds may exist for different cases. **Catching the NameError** could be another one.

```
t = 'asdfas'
print(isinstance(t, str))
try:
    print(isinstance(t, MyClass))
except NameError:
    print(False)
```

Seems to me, that such a construct may appear in future python. Like typed python, which is quite new. And in typed python we have a possibility to use future types, in apos.